# optparse python methods options commandline

Tags: python, methods, command-line

I want to call python script with options like following:

```
$python script.py --i fname.txt --j c --k True
```

I have written a python script to open a file if condition true; now I want to make it commandline, I want to use "optparse" module for that and I have written the follwoing script so far, btu I can't not get the desire results, python executing the scritp without any error though. Any ideas how ti fix it ?? Thanks !

```
import optparse    

def ab(i, j, k=None): 
    if (j == c):
        e = 'fname.txt'
        with open(e, 'rU') as use:
             for u in use:
                  u = use.plit()
                  with open(i, 'rU') as use2:
                       for u2 in use2:
                            u2 = u2.plit()
                            if k:
                                 if u[0] in u2:
                                      print(u2)


def main():
     parser = pstparse.OptaionParser('usage %prog --i <input file> --k <> --j <>')
     parser.add_option('--i', dest = 'filename')
     parser.add_option('--j', type = 'string')
     parser.add_option('--k', type = 'string')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
     if (options.i == '--i'):
          args == i
     if (options.j == '--j'):
          args == j
     if (options.k == '--k'):
          args == k

     if __name__ =="__main__":
         main()
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation in your script? If so the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line looks out of place, as it is within `main()`. If you moved it out you would probably get an error due to the typo in `pstparse.OptaionParser`. After that you probably want to specify a `dest = ` for all of the arguments like you did for `--i` so you can use them elsewhere. Otherwise, there is a convention to use `--` for strings of more than one character and `-` for single characters, which all of yours are.

Comment: Use `argparse` instead. It is in the standard library starting with Python 2.7, and a version tested with 2.3+ [is available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse).